# Regarding Time series data

Tags: time-series

I am new to econometrics. I have data have $240$ observations ($20\times12$) consisting of monthly closing prices for $1000$ stocks.

This is time series data or panel data?
In my knowledge it is time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no doubt about it. It is time series data. Because it consists of observations on several variables over time.